# In leaflet.js how do you fire a fancybox event from a polygon object click?

Tags: jquery, leaflet

Now I would like to fire a fancybox event from a polygon object click. This is my object:

```
new L.Polygon([
        [79.07181, -100.63477], 
        [79.06348, -90.43945], 
        [77.52312, -90.52734], 
        [77.50412, -94.21875], 
        [77.41825, -94.35059], 
        [77.40868, -96.72363], 
        [77.51362, -96.81152], 
        [77.53261, -100.63477], 
        [79.07181, -100.63477]
  ], {'label': popup_flor, 'popup': content_flor}),
```

The variable 'content_flor' contains the building description. Rather than show that description, I'd like to bring up the fancybox iframe.

Another team member has provided a list of links to building descriptions.

```
    <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="flrs.html">The Building Name</a>
```

What I'd like to do is have the code that is executed by clicking the link happen when the visitor clicks the polygon object itself. Is it possible to do this? Something like this pseudocode:

```
  new L.Polygon([
        [79.07181, -100.63477],
        ...
        [79.07181, -100.63477]
  ], {'label': popup_flor, 'popup': callFancyboxIframe('flrs.html')}),
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `click` event of the polygon to do what ever you want, in your  case open the fancybox.

```
//Handle click on polygon
var onPolyClick = function(event){
    //open fancybox here
    var label = event.target.options.label;
    var content = event.target.options.popup;
    var otherStuff = event.target.options.otherStuff;
    alert("Clicked on polygon with label:" +label +" and content:" +content +". Also otherStuff set to:" +otherStuff);
};
//Create polygon
var popup_flor ="MyLabel";
var content_flor ="MyContent";
var poly = new L.Polygon([
        [79.07181, -100.63477], 
        [79.06348, -90.43945], 
        [77.52312, -90.52734], 
        [77.50412, -94.21875], 
        [77.41825, -94.35059], 
        [77.40868, -96.72363], 
        [77.51362, -96.81152], 
        [77.53261, -100.63477], 
        [79.07181, -100.63477]
  ], {'label': popup_flor, 'popup': content_flor, 'otherStuff': 'abc123'});
poly.on('click', onPolyClick);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/guspersson/yfe1g5zs/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in the scope of my project. I see how it could work, but I need create the poly as it is defined above in my example. Is there a way to bind the poly.on event in that framework?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how to make it work with my framework! I just declared the polygons as vars as in your example, then grouped the named polygon variables and applied the same code as before. Works great!

Comment: Good for you. Please consider posting the solution as an answer so other people can learn from your problem.